# How to create individual object from a list of object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, object

I have a list of different objects like this:

```
Object: { "march 2019": 21, "april 2019": 23, "may 2019": 121, etc... }
```

How can I set up individual objects from this previous list in javascript or jQuery?

```
  Object:   { "march 2019": 21 }
  Object:   { "april 2019": 23 }
  Object:   { "may 2019": 121 }
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You could do with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

**updated** with 3 different answer

```js
const obj = { "march 2019": 21, "april 2019": 23, "may 2019": 121};

let res = Object.entries(obj).map((a,b)=>({[a[0]]:a[1]}));

//array object
console.log(res)

//single object 
console.log(Object.assign({},...res))

//object object
console.log(res.reduce((a,b,c)=>(a[c]=b,a),{}))
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but it is not possible to have individual object, not contained in an array ?

Comment: @タナカ how would that work? You need something to contain the multiple new objects you're creating and an array works best for that

Comment: @prasanth Instead to have an array of 4 objects, I need these 4 objects separately like
`code
Object: { "march 2019": 21 }
Object:{ "april 2019": 23 }
Object:{ "may 2019": 121 }`:

Comment: @タナカ if you have array instead of single object. Do with array#map before .`yourarray.map(item=> Object.entries(item).map((a,b)=>({[a[0]]:a[1]})) )`

Comment: I have 1 object containing different value and I wanted to transform them as individual object. I edited my main question

Comment: @タナカ . still the question same as your previous question.please clarify more

Comment: Thanks for patience. My goal is to have without any array like this :
`code
  Object:   { "march 2019": 21 }
  Object:   { "april 2019": 23 }
  Object:   { "may 2019": 121 }
`
if I use     Object.entries(item).map((a,b)=>({[a[0]]:a[1]})) ) I will get an array containing an array containing each Object. I would like to know if I can get directly each Object without any array

Comment: @タナカ . not possible to create a object  without key. so i was recreate the object index as key .And also i added 3 diff answer. choose any one

Answer (score 0):

You can either store the object in array or you can directly use inside the loop :

```js
const obj = { "march 2019": 21, "april 2019": 23, "may 2019": 121};

Object.entries(obj).forEach(ob=>console.log({[ob[0]]:ob[1]}))
```

Hopefully it should work

Comment: thanks for your help. Result is what I need but it's only display by console.log ? I need to modify the List of Object. It is possible without console.log ?

Comment: you can't store this value ({ "march 2019": 21 }
{ "april 2019": 23 }
{ "may 2019": 121 }) in a variable. Either you can use array or object to store these value or directly use inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, this will give a single object:

```
let input_dict = { "march 2019": 21, "april 2019": 23, "may 2019": 121};

let output_dict = {};
Object.keys(input_dict).map(function (item) {
    !output_dict.hasOwnProperty(item)?output_dict[item] = input_dict[item]:'';
});
console.log(output_dict)
```